# Rails 3 render form has text not has html

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, render

I would like to rendex a form (in a specific div) without refreshing the window. The problem is that

```
$('#details').html("<%= escape_javascript(render('form')) %>");
```

is rendering my form hast text instead of html.

The code:
in my index.html.erb I have

```
<%= link_to 'Edit note', edit_note_path(:id => Note.user_note(wine.id,current_user.id)),:remote => true %><br/>
```

then In my Controller I have

```
 def edit
    @note = Note.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js {}
    end
  end
```

Then in edit.js.erb I have:

```
$('#details').html("<%= escape_javascript(render('form')) %>");
```

What happens is that the div details get's the form has text not as an html form appearance.

I'm using Rails 3.08, Jquery ..and so far no problems with the ajax ..is just in this particular case that I want to render html instead of text.

am I missing something ?  Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#details').html("<%== escape_javascript(render('form')) %>");
```

(Note the use of `<%==` in place of `<%=`).

Comment: Wow perfect it worked! Thanks ! What's the difference between <%== and <%= ? 
The problem now is that my form fields come with html in it like 
"textarea>  div>  <div class=actions>    <input id=note_submit name=commit type=submit value=Create Note />  div>form> " Why that happens ?

Comment: `<%=` escapes the input (converts `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;`, among other things), whereas `<%==` does not.

Comment: Ok nice, thanks!How can I avoid that this rendered form does not get filled of html coinde in the text fields ?

Comment: It's hard to say, without knowing how the HTML got into the textarea in the first place.  Are you storing escaped HTML in the database?

Comment: No no html in database. I have a grails scaffold generated form. For example afther a text field prints out "div>" and in a text-area value besides the value (from database) prints out "textarea> div> <div class=actions> <input id=note_submit name=commit type=submit value=Create Note /> div>form>" .. and not even the form submit buttons are rendered. Thanks again :)

Comment: I will Post a Question related this problem with the code to make it more clear. Thanks for your help

Comment: Here is my other question and the answer related this problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6479048/rails-3-form-rendered-in-ajax-get-html-mixed-with-text-fields-values